# Selecting and using operators per partition group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following table that stores sporting event data. I'm trying to find which events have increased in attendance upon returning to the same country.

```
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| EventId  | EventName  | Country   | Attendance  | EventDate  |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|        1 | Soccer1    | Australia |       12000 | 2015-01-01 |
|        2 | Soccer2    | Mexico    |       35999 | 2016-02-02 |
|        3 | Soccer3    | Australia |       13999 | 2015-03-22 |
|        4 | Football1  | Japan     |       13555 | 2003-11-12 |
|        5 | Football2  | Japan     |       12222 | 2004-01-01 |
|        6 | Football3  | Canada    |       13444 | 2003-02-23 |
|        7 | Tennis1    | America   |       10000 | 2014-01-02 |
|        8 | Tennis2    | America   |       12111 | 2015-10-01 |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sports](
    [EventId] [int] NULL,
    [EventName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Attendance] [int] NULL,
    [EventDate] [date] NULL
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Soccer1', N'Australia', 12000, CAST(N'2015-01-01' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (2, N'Soccer2', N'Mexico', 35999, CAST(N'2016-02-02' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (3, N'Soccer3', N'Australia', 13999, CAST(N'2015-03-22' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (4, N'Football1', N'Japan', 13555, CAST(N'2003-11-12' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (5, N'Football2', N'Japan', 12222, CAST(N'2004-01-01' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (6, N'Football3', N'Canada', 13444, CAST(N'2003-02-23' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (7, N'Tennis1', N'America', 10000, CAST(N'2014-01-02' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[Sports] ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (8, N'Tennis2', N'America', 12111, CAST(N'2015-10-01' AS Date))
```

So I created a CTE to find which countries have held an event more than once and then tried to use the `lead` function ordered by `eventdate` to see if the most recent date had higher attendance.

But when those conditions are met, I want to display both the row with the higher attendance and the row with the previous event also. My attempt only shows the row with the most recent date.

```
with t as (
select EventId, EventName, Country, Attendance, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),EventDate,106) as Date
from Sports
where Country in (select Country from Sports group by Country having count(*)>=2)
),
s as (

select *, LEAD(Attendance) over (partition by Country order by cast([Date] as datetime) desc) as PrevAttendance 
from t 
)

select EventName, Country, Attendance, Date
from s
where  Attendance > PrevAttendance
```

So my question is also, in general how do you perform operations on each partition/window set in SQL Server 2014. Because in this example, if there was a lot more events per country, I might also want to check if the most recent attendance is at least greater than any previous, not just the most immediately previous event.

Hopefully that makes sense, thanks in advance for any help.

So my expected outcome for this table would be as follows:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| EventId  | EventName  | Country   | Attendance  | EventDate  |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|        1 | Soccer1    | Australia |       12000 | 2015-01-01 |
|        3 | Soccer3    | Australia |       13999 | 2015-03-22 |
|        7 | Tennis1    | America   |       10000 | 2014-01-02 |
|        8 | Tennis2    | America   |       12111 | 2015-10-01 |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: why is Canada  not included in group  ?

Comment: You question, in general, is too broad.  You should be more specific about the question being asked.

Comment: Sorry ,I got it...if that is for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the two most recent rows.

```
with
cte as (
   select *,
      lead(Attendance) -- next row
      over (partition by Country
            order by EventDate desc) as PrevAttendance,
      lag(Attendance) -- previous row
      over (partition by Country
            order by EventDate desc) as NextAttendance,
      ROW_NUMBER() 
      over (partition by Country
            order by EventDate desc) as rn

from sports
)
select * 
from cte
     -- only the last two rows
     -- when last row's value is greater than previous row's value 
where (rn = 1 and Attendance > PrevAttendance)
   or (rn = 2 and Attendance < NextAttendance)
```

Use a cumulative MIN to find the minimum value over all previous rows:

```
MIN(Attendance) 
over (partition by Country 
      order by EventDate desc
          -- all rows before the current row
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE #sports(
    [EventId] [int] NULL,
    [EventName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Attendance] [int] NULL,
    [EventDate] [date] NULL
);
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (1, N'Soccer1', N'Australia', 12000, CAST(N'2015-01-01' AS Date))
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (2, N'Soccer2', N'Mexico', 35999, CAST(N'2016-02-02' AS Date))
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (3, N'Soccer3', N'Australia', 13999, CAST(N'2015-03-22' AS Date))
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (4, N'Football1', N'Japan', 13555, CAST(N'2003-11-12' AS Date))
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (5, N'Football2', N'Japan', 12222, CAST(N'2004-01-01' AS Date))
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (6, N'Football3', N'Canada', 13444, CAST(N'2003-02-23' AS Date))
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (7, N'Tennis1', N'America', 10000, CAST(N'2014-01-02' AS Date))
INSERT INTO #sports ([EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]) VALUES (8, N'Tennis2', N'America', 12111, CAST(N'2015-10-01' AS Date))


;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        pat=CASE 
            WHEN LAG(Attendance) OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY EventId)IS NULL THEN 0 
            WHEN Attendance<LAG(Attendance) OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY EventId) THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END,
        patid=LAG(EventId) OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY EventId)
    FROM
        #sports
)
SELECT
    [EventId], [EventName], [Country], [Attendance], [EventDate]
FROM
    cte 
WHERE 
    pat=1
UNION
SELECT
    inn.[EventId], inn.[EventName], inn.[Country], inn.[Attendance], inn.[EventDate]
FROM
    cte AS ou
    INNER JOIN cte AS inn ON
        inn.EventId=ou.patid
WHERE
    ou.pat=1
ORDER BY
    EventId;

DROP TABLE #sports;
```

Results:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| EventId | EventName |  Country  | Attendance | EventDate  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|       1 | Soccer1   | Australia |      12000 | 2015-01-01 |
|       3 | Soccer3   | Australia |      13999 | 2015-03-22 |
|       7 | Tennis1   | America   |      10000 | 2014-01-02 |
|       8 | Tennis2   | America   |      12111 | 2015-10-01 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: The UNION is there to filter out doubles in cases there are 3 events, each increasing in attendance.

Comment: Where are you checking that the attendance increased for a country *in the same sport*?  The sample data currently happens to work in your favor even if you ignore this detail because no country plays two different sports. But according to the OP, it should be comparing by same event returning to the same country.

Comment: @mellamokb There is no column that just has a sport in it. If I would change the query to also partition on EventName, the results would no longer match the expected output the OP has in his question (results would be empty). In any case if there is such an extra field to partition on, it's easy to add that to the query.

Comment: The column `EventName` technically has enough information to figure it out (by removing the number from the end).  Not ideal, but can be implemented pretty easily as well.  I agree that there is much to be desired in the OP's sample data anyway, but just wanted to point out that deficiency for the OP's awareness.

Comment: @mellamokb Good point. I'll leave that as an excercise for the OP ;-)